# Бесконечный цикл while(). Enter для выхода

Tags: c, циклы

Что в этом коде не так?

Код Си:

```
int number = 0;

while(number != '\0' ) {
    printf("\nEnter number (or Enter to Exit): ");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    printf("\nDec: %d.\n", number);
    printf("Hex: %x.\n", number);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

А что Вас тут не устраивает?

Да, цикл `while` не будет исполняться, т.к. перед ним

```
number = 0;
```

а `'\0'` == 0.

--

[[[[[[@dr_kraken](/users/20119/dr_kraken)](/users/20119/dr_kraken)](/users/20119/dr_kraken)](/users/20119/dr_kraken)](/users/20119/dr_kraken)](/users/20119/dr_kraken), Вы все-таки писали бы в вопросе, *а чего хотите получить?*

---

**UPDATE**

Вот вариант для выхода по ENTER

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main ()
{
  char s[1000];
  int n;

  while(fputs("Enter number or ENTER for Exit: ", stdout), fflush(stdout),
        fgets(s, 1000, stdin)) {
    if (s[0] == '\n') 
      break;

    if (sscanf(s, "%d", &n) == 1)
      printf ("Hex: 0x%02x Dec: %d\n", n, n);
    else if (s[strspn(s, " \t\f\v\r\n")]) 
      puts ("Wrong input"); // в строке есть что-то кроме "пробелов" и это не число
  }

  return puts("Bye") == EOF;
}
```

[[[[[[@dr_kraken](/users/20119/dr_kraken)](/users/20119/dr_kraken)](/users/20119/dr_kraken)](/users/20119/dr_kraken)](/users/20119/dr_kraken)](/users/20119/dr_kraken), а вообще почитайте что-нибудь по [stdio](http://infohost.nmt.edu/~eweiss/222_book/222_book/0201433079/ch05.html) и [Terminal I/O](http://infohost.nmt.edu/~eweiss/222_book/222_book/0201433079/ch18.html)

*Обновление*

Если хотите вводить и печатать числа, то наверное, проще всего так:

```
#define TEXT "Enter NUMBER (or anyNOTnumber to Exit): "

  printf ("%s", TEXT); fflush(stdout);
  while (scanf("%d", &n) == 1)
    printf ("Hex: 0x%02x Dec: %d\n%s", n, n, TEXT), fflush(stdout);
```

а если любые символы, то такой цикл

```
  int n;
  while (scanf("%c", (char *)(&n)) == 1)
    printf ("char '%c' Hex: 0x%02x Dec: %d\n", n, n, n);
```

должен завершаться по EOF (^D или ^Z в винде)

*Обновление 2*

[[@klopp](/users/6550/klopp)](/users/6550/klopp), `Enter to Exit`, естественно, не будет.  Я просто пока не стал углубляться в тонкости работы `scanf()` (и вообще `stdio`).

--

[[[[[[@dr_kraken](/users/20119/dr_kraken)](/users/20119/dr_kraken)](/users/20119/dr_kraken)](/users/20119/dr_kraken)](/users/20119/dr_kraken)](/users/20119/dr_kraken), проверять результат функции ввода надо всегда.

А конкретно к этому случаю -- если `scanf` возвращает 1, то все хорошо -- ввели число. В противном случае что-то не так. Или конец файла, или ошибка ввода-вывода, или вместо цифр на входе буквы (и т.п.). Читайте `man scanf`.

Там написано, что `Enter` при чтении с форматом `%d` пропускается.

Для выхода по `Enter` надо или читать по одному символу или построчно и анализировать ввод.

Comment: @avp, кажется, в вопрос принципиальная ошибка в "or Enter to Exit"... Не будет оно Exit по Enter :-)

Comment: Объясните, зачем == 1 в (scanf("%d", &n) == 1)? Что scanf() возвращает количество введенных данных, и это число сравнивается с 1? Но и без == 1, код все равно будет работать. Раз так, то зачем ==1? А нельзя сделать, чтобы цикл прекратился, как только пользователь просто нажмет Enter?

Answer (score 5):

Кроме очевидного выхода без входа в цикл (`n` и так равно 0 с самого начала), вы предполагаете, что в переменную `n` будет записан 0 если пользователь вместо ввода числа нажмёт Enter (введёт пустую строку). Но это не так. `scanf()` будет читать поток до получения EOF, а EOF - это не Enter.

Измените условие на "Enter 0, or not number, or Ctrl+D to exit" и всё получится.

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы вышел по Enter?

Comment: Написал пример в **update** своего ответа.